# Flutter bloc new version deprecated mapEventToState

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a bloc hierarchy, where in the child bloc's `mapEvenToState` I used `super.mapEventToState`. In the newer version of the bloc package, `mapEventToState` is deprecated.

What should I use instead of `super.mapEventToState`? I know about `on<Event>`, but what is the equivalent of `super.mapEventToState`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it should be something like that in your bloc class

```
class ProductsBloc extends Bloc<ProductsEvent, ProductsState> {
  final GetMoreProducts moreProductsUsecase;
  final GetProducts getProductsUsecase;

  ProductsBloc({
    required this.moreProductsUsecase,
    required this.getProductsUsecase,
  }) : super(ProductsInitial()) {

    on<GetProductsEvent>(_onGetProducts);

  }
```

and the function call can be like this

```
_onGetProducts(GetProductsEvent event, Emitter<ProductsState> emit) async {
    emit(LoadingProductsState());
    var result = await getProductsUsecase();
    result.fold(
        (l) => emit(LoadFailedState()),
        (r) => { emit(ProductsLoadedState(products: products, isReachedMax: false)),
            });
  }
```